# Scaling code transforms in an MVC app

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, msbuild

I have a web app that maintains all configuration values in either web.config and a custom config file for application-specific settings, such as folder locations and service endpoints.

I am using code transforms to manage this. There is no problem with this functionality.
The problem which I am having has to do with scale; we currently have 60 different files of each type. These are for Dev, QA, UAT, and production configurations. We use the figuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform" paradigm.

It is becoming a full time job just to manage these settings! I am sure that I am missing a key concept in the transformation process.

How can this be better made to accommodate scale, without adding a developer just to maintain these configurations?